# What was the biggest blunder made by Boris Spassky in Game 6?

Tags: world-championship, famous-players, blunder, famous-moves

I just wanted to inquire about the biggest mistake or blunder by Boris Spassky In game no. 6 against Bobby Fischer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am tempted to say "agreeing to continue the match after Fischer's protests!" which some argue was a key psychological defeat.  If you're looking for specific moves that were mistakes, there are a few candidates.  I haven't looked at all annotations, but have Kasparov's *My Great Predecessors, vol 4* handy and looking over his notes, it would be either (notations and comments are his):

20. ...d4?
    "This move, conceding the important c4-square, was rightly condemned by the commentators.  20. ...Nf6 really was better...but the most accurate solution was the continuation 20. ...c4"

and

22. ...Rb8?!
    "The last critical moment."

Answer (score 0):

The biggest was 36...Qe8. Other than that, 20...d4 and maybe 18...Qf8 could be called "weak" if not outright "blunder".